# Why does only the last of these duplicated directives work as intended?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that needs to display certain numbers of images based on the width of the screen, however I have noticed that when repeating this directive using an ng-repeat only the last implementation of the directive works as intended. I think this may be something to do with calling $apply() but window re-sizes do not trigger digests so I need to in order to see the changes reflected on the page.

I'm not getting any errors in the console. Is there any way to solve this?

Here's the directive.

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

    angular.module('xxxx')
        .directive('xxx', xxx);

  function xxxxx ($window, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      templateUrl: 'xxxx',
      scope :{
        data : "="
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        scope.componentName = 'xxxxx';
        var pageWidth = window.innerWidth;
        scope.resultLimit = scope.data.conferences.length;

        scope.setResultLimit = function(){

          console.log('triggered');


            pageWidth = window.innerWidth;
            if(pageWidth < 768){
              if(scope.data.conferences.length % 2 !== 0){
                console.log('Less than 768');
                scope.resultLimit = scope.data.conferences.length - 1;
              } else{
                scope.resultLimit = scope.data.conferences.length;
              }
            }
            if(pageWidth >= 768 && pageWidth < 1200){
              if(scope.data.conferences.length % 3 !== 0){
                console.log('Greater than 768 and less than 1200');
                scope.resultLimit = scope.data.conferences.length - (scope.data.conferences.length % 3);
              } else{
                scope.resultLimit = scope.data.conferences.length;
              }
            }
            if(pageWidth >= 1200){
              console.log('greater than 1200');
              if(scope.data.conferences.length % 5 !== 0){

                scope.resultLimit = scope.data.conferences.length - (scope.data.conferences.length % 5);

              } else{
                scope.resultLimit = scope.data.conferences.length;
              }
            }

            console.log(scope.resultLimit);
            //scope.$apply();




        };

        window.onresize = function(event){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.setResultLimit();
          })

        };

        scope.setResultLimit();

      }
    };
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `onresize` event handler (`window.onresize` property) in every next directive initialization. You need to bind several events with `addEventListener` method. So it will be:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.setResultLimit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise there was a difference in the addEventListener and  onresize methods.

Comment: This is very important difference that with `onresize` property you can only register one event handler.